# How can I disable Tor's automatic IP circuit renewal process?

Tags: onion-services, security, vpn, ip-address, login

I have an issue with this process when trying to log in or authenticate to a site where I only want to use the VPN and don't want the IP to change automatically at that time, as it interferes with the login process. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable it completely, but you can increase the time by changing the `MaxCircuitDirtiness` torrc option. The highest allowed value is `30*24*60*60 = 2592000` which is 2592000 seconds (720 hours). Changing this value may reduce the privacy provided to you by Tor.